# How to exec store procedure with many parameter to restAPI in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, api, parameters, exec

I have 2 apps, 1 is front and and the other 1 is webapi server.

In webapi, i have to exec a Store Procedure on mssql server. That SP has 52 input parameters.
I want to call that SP in My API Controller.
My question is how to pass those 52 parameter from my Front end to my API server.
I'm successfully testing with static parameter in Postman.

The frontend is Laravel 5.8 and my API server is Laravel 6.2

Here's my API controller, still with static parameters that I want to get as an array '$allmyparams' (if possible) from my Frontend

```
    public function as_add_reg($allmyparams)
{

    //these are static params for testing purpose
    $param1 = "ID02007160013";
    $param2 = "2020-07-17 00:00:00";
    $param3 = "00-00-77-32";
    $param4 = '00128'; 
    $param5 =  '02        '; 
    $param6 =  '11:27'; 
    $param7 = '06        '; 
    $param8 = '          '; 
    $param9 = 'DESY ARIANA'; 
    $param10 = ''; 
    $param11 = 'RAYA KRONJO '; 
    $param12 = 'TANGERANG'; 
    $param13 = '     '; 
    $param14 = '     '; 
    $param15 = '               '; 
    $param16 = '               '; 
    $param17 = '          '; 
    $param18 = 'TANGERANG                     '; 
    $param19 = '002       '; 
    $param20 = 'P'; 
    $param21 = '                              '; 
    $param22 = '1978-02-03 00:00:00'; 
    $param23 = 'none      '; 
    $param24 = '               '; 
    $param25 = '00002     '; 
    $param26 = '$0.0000'; 
    $param27 = '                         '; 
    $param28 = '                                                  '; 
    $param29 = 'none      '; 
    $param30 =  0; 
    $param31 = 42; 
    $param32 =  5; 
    $param33 =  13; 
    $param34 =  '2020-07-16 11:28:44.920'; 
    $param35 =  'mssql'; 
    $param36 =  0; 
    $param37 =  '               '; 
    $param38 =  '                         '; 
    $param39 =  '2020-07-16 00:00:00'; 
    $param40 =  'none      '; 
    $param41 = ''; 
    $param42 =  ''; 
    $param43 = '          '; 
    $param44 = 'none      '; 
    $param45 =  ''; 
    $param46 =  ''; 
    $param47 =  'none      '; 
    $param48 =  'none      '; 
    $param49 =  'none      '; 
    $param50 =  0; 
    $param51 =  0; 
    $param52 = '1';

    $referral_registers = DB::connection('as_api')
        ->select('EXEC reg_Insert ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?', 
        array($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $param5, $param6, $param7, $param8, $param9, $param10,
         $param11, $param12, $param13, $param14, $param15, $param16, $param17, $param18, $param19, $param20,
         $param21, $param22, $param23, $param24, $param25, $param26, $param27, $param28, $param29, $param30, 
         $param31, $param32, $param33, $param34, $param35, $param36, $param37, $param38, $param39, $param40, 
         $param41, $param42, $param43, $param44, $param45, $param46, $param47, $param48, $param49, $param50, 
         $param51, $param52));

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $referral_registers
    ]);
}
```

And In the frontend, here's the function that calls that webAPI server

```
            $allmyparam=arrray(
               "param1"=>1',
               "param2"=>"example",
               ...  
               "param52"=>"example",
            );

            $response2 = $client->get($webapi_url . '/api/heru/as_add_reg/' . $allmyparams, [
                'cookies' => $cookieJar,
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $webapi_token,
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without arguing the solution you share, here.

i think you are looking for:

```
  public function controller_method(Request $request) {
     $request->all();
  }
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests
To get a more detailed explanation on how to handle request input

Or.. if you are having a flat array with only values, and want to get it as as array with key and values

You could use collection helpers of laravel mapWithKeys

See: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys

Based on your comment, i guess you don't get what i mean..

```
$param1 = "ID02007160013";
$param2 = "2020-07-17 00:00:00";
$param3 = "00-00-77-32";
// ... and so on

//could be done as
$params[] = "val1"
$params[] = "val2"

// Then for example you can access it as an array
//Just like accessing $params

//If you need it as separate values, on a function argument, you could use //the spread operator like

...$params
```

See: https://laravel-news.com/spread-operator-in-array-expressions-coming-to-php-7-4

For some examples.. (and only works if you have a recent PHP version)

Then if you want it to convert to a an associative array

```php
foreach ($params as $index => $param) {
 $newArray["param${index}"] = $param;
}
```

You could also use the https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections
helper methods for these, but guess, these are harder to understand for you for now.

.. Sending it as query parameter

```
$client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org', [
    'query' => ['foo' => 'bar']
]);
```

See: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters

If you insist having it as an string you could also use the native php function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, however it's a strange design in REST conventions to have 50+ get parameters, which are named...param1 till 50.

You decide where you do the conversion... the $request->all() can only be used from where your router call the controller, else you might use the Request facade, if you still want to access the input.

Comment: I just updated the answer with a link, explaining how to handle request input, the laravel way.

Comment: i want to store data to table trough API, and i dont need access to input

Comment: could you pls give me some example based on my provided codes, to give me some idea how to do it

Comment: I added some samples in various ways

Comment: and, how do i pass those arrays to webapi server?

Comment: One more example provided